# Loop over dictionary and add something

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I want to add to my dictionary `dfList` an id and a dataframe. But my adding doesn't work. How could I add to my dictionary the id and the df, that later I want to say give me from the dictionary `dfList` the `dataframe` with the `id` `file1.csv`.

So how could I add this in a loop and later give me the rom the dictionary `dfList` the `dataframe` with the `id` `file1.csv` back?

```py
csvfiles = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']
dfList = []
for index, csvfile in enumerate(csvfiles): 
    file = os.path.join('C:/Documents', csvfile)
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    #dfList[index]['id'] = csvfiles
    #dfList[index]['dataframe'] = df
    dfList.append(dfList['id'] = csvfiles)
```

What I want at the end

```
dfList = [{'id': 'file1.csv', 'dataframe': df}, {'id': 'file2.csv', 'dataframe': df}]
```

The below code is for testing. In case you want to try something out.
Here is a min. code for Testing. If you want to try:

```py
d = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'horstid': [11, 22, 33, 33]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
d2 = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4]]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
csvfiles = [df, df2]

dfList = []
for index, csvfile in enumerate(csvfiles): 
    
    #dfList[index]['id'] = str("File"+index)
    #dfList[index]['dataframe'] = csvfile 

# What I want is
# Get the dataframe with the id File1
# df_new = dfList[df = (dfList['id] == 'File1')]
# df_new
# [OUT]
#    id  horstid        
# 0   1       11  
# 1   2       22      
# 2   3       33  
# 3   4       33
```

Comment: Your `dfList` appears to be a list of dictionaries.  Is that really what you want, or would you want to access a dataframe for a particular file with syntax like `mydict['file1.csv']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this structure:

```
{'file1.csv': <df1>, 'file2.csv': <df2> ... }
```

Dont use a list. Use a dictionary. Use the file name as key and the data frame as value:

```
dDict[csvfile] = df
```

Then get the dataframe by its filename:

```
dDict[filename]  # --> <data>
```